# Why isn't the time complexity of constructing a Fenwick tree tighter than $O(n\lg n)$?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, binary-trees, amortized-analysis

## Intuition:

Suppose I have an array of nonzero integer values $A[n]$ and a partially constructed Fenwick tree of this array: $F[k], n>k$. I can see why inserting the next element would be worst case $O(\lg n)$. The number of elements accessed from $F[0:k]$ to calculate $F[k+1]$ is equal to the number of trailing zeroes in $(k+1)_2$ which is at most $\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor$. There are $n$ elements, so this is $O(n\lg n)$. [Wikipedia seems to agree as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree#Description)

## Thoughts:

**NOTE:** I am using [this algorithm](http://pastebin.com/7aTP9t53).

Consider the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$ with exactly $j$ trailing zeroes in their binary representation, $j<{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}$. Since the leftmost ${\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}-(j+1)$ digits can be freely assigned so long as the resulting number is less than $n$ ($j+1$ because the $(j+1)th$ digit from the right must be a $1$), there are between $2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor-j-1}$ and $2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor-j)}$ such numbers for any $n$.

Let an operation be defined as the summation of two numbers, which is assumed to be a constant time operation. (The other operations, like insertion, are also in constant time and are performed a constant number of times, hence they are ignored) Thus, for $j$ trailing zeroes, $j$ operations must be performed.

As a result, the total number of operations to perform is at most $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor} j2^{{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}-j}$. It must also be true that $2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}≤n<2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor + 1}$. Note that both maxima occur when $n_2$ is filled with ones. If we take this case, the mean number of operations for any $j$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ should be:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor} j2^{{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}-j}}{2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor +1}-1}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^n \frac {j}{2^{j}}}
=1$

Now, if we take the other extreme, where $\lg(n)\in\mathbb{Z}$ ($n_2$ is a one trailed exclusively by zeroes) then there are exactly $\lg(n)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lg(n)-1} j2^{{\lg(n)-1}-j}$ operations to be performed over exactly $2^{\lg(n)}$ numbers, and the limit also approaches $1$. Testing seems to reveal that no other values of $n$ with the same $\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor$ values have a higher mean number of operations per element than these.

**If the amortized cost of inserting each element is indeed constant, shouldn't constructing the tree be $\Theta(n)$ time?**

### Testing:

I've tested the ranges between admittedly small consecutive powers of two, both by applying the summation and by brute force, and the results seem to agree:

Code using summation: http://pastebin.com/T3EEM7qz

Code using brute force: http://pastebin.com/sxdAkgxn

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did not check the details of your analysis, but what you did is called *amortized* analysis. Congratulations! (Avoid using the word "average"; that way lies the association with expected time resp. average-case, which is not what you do.)

Comment: @Raphael I'll be honest, I'd always thought amortized analysis was average-case analysis. After a bit of searching, I see this is not the case. Thanks for clarifying! As for the term 'average', what might be a less misleading term in this context? I can see the problem, but what I'm calculating is the actual mean of something.

Comment: If you sum up the (exact) costs of a sequence of $n$ operations, you get the *total* cost of this sequence. Dividing by $n$ is not meaningful per se (you don't get out a quantity that "actually exists"); we call the result the *amortized* cost of (each) single operation. So you can stick with that. If you want to emphasize that each operation get assigned the same share of the total cost, I think *mean* (as in sample mean) is probably safe to use.

Comment: @Raphael Ah, that makes sense. I've edited to improve the terminology. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Technically it *is* $O(n\log n)$, since big-O is an upper bound only, but your tighter bound of $O(n)$ is also correct.  (Without loss of generality, it suffices to restrict $n$ to powers of two; then the proof is easy.)

Comment: Until the OP's edit about 30 minutes ago, I hadn't seen that algorithm, and so assumed s/he (and Wikipedia) were talking about the naive one consisting of just n calls to the usual update function.  Indeed the now-linked algorithm is effectively the same as mine (but "pulls" instead of "pushes").

Comment: The claim "tighter bound of $O(n)$ is also correct" requires proof, as the other answer points out that it is unlikely.

Comment: @KennethKho Unfortunately the question was unclear, and these answers are discussing different algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT: Everything down to the horizontal line was written under the assumption that the algorithm being used was the obvious naive one, in which we simply call update(i, A[i]) for every $1 \le i \le n$.  But the OP had a cleverer algorithm in mind... which s/he has now actually described ;-)]**

The main problem with your analysis is that the number of Fenwick tree operations (additions or writes to the array) required to **update** it with some value $i$ is not equal to the number of trailing zero bits in $i$.  It's equal to the number of range sums that $i$ needs to be included in, which can all be found by repeatedly adding the least significant 1-bit present in $i$ to $i$ until it escapes past the maximum possible index, i.e., by using the update rule

```
void update(int idx ,int val){
    while (idx <= MaxVal){
        tree[idx] += val;
        idx += (idx & -idx);
    }
}
```

taken from [this nice tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/).

In the best case, which is when $n$ is 1 less than a power of 2, this works out to be $\lfloor \lg n \rfloor - y_i - f_i + 1$ operations, where $y_i$ is the total number of 1-bits in $i$, and $f_i$ is the number of trailing 0-bits in i.  (Every *non-trailing* 0-bit position $0 \leq j \leq \lfloor \lg n \rfloor$ in $i$, including those $j$ for which $2^j > i$, is the position of the lowest 1-bit of exactly 1 index that $i$ contributes to, and each of them can be reached in constant time due to the magic of ripple carries.)  The worst case occurs when $n$ is a power of 2: this adds exactly 1 more operation to every update over the best case.  (The worst-case value of $i$ is of course $i = 1$.)

None of this rules out the possibility that the naive construction algorithm actually is O(n) -- but it seems very unlikely.  [Using code similar to yours](http://pastebin.com/FL9RNeNp) I find that empirically, the mean number of operations required by the naive construction algorithm seems to increase logarithmically with $n$:

```
NEW WORST: 1.000000 for n=1
NEW WORST: 1.500000 for n=2
NEW WORST: 2.000000 for n=4
NEW WORST: 2.500000 for n=8
NEW WORST: 3.000000 for n=16
NEW WORST: 3.500000 for n=32
NEW WORST: 4.000000 for n=64
NEW WORST: 4.500000 for n=128
NEW WORST: 5.000000 for n=256
NEW WORST: 5.500000 for n=512
NEW WORST: 6.000000 for n=1024
NEW WORST: 6.500000 for n=2048
NEW WORST: 7.000000 for n=4096
NEW WORST: 7.500000 for n=8192
NEW WORST: 8.000000 for n=16384
NEW WORST: 8.500000 for n=32768
```

Finally, in case you're interested, I came up with [a simple in-place algorithm for this that uses exactly 1 addition operation per array index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070683/47984) in response to a similar question on SO.

---

P.S.: Since I actually went through your question *before* realising that the thing you were counting wasn't quite right, let me just detail a couple of small further problems with it:

To get an upper bound on the mean you need to pick a *lower* bound on n to go in the denominator of the limit, e.g.:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor} j2^{{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}-j}}{2^{\lfloor \lg(n) \rfloor}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^n \frac {j}{2^{j}}}$,

and in any case,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^n \frac {j}{2^{j}}}
=2$,

not 1 as you claimed.  (Obviously this wouldn't change the asymptotic complexity; also, although this constant appears to be loose from looking at your graphs, I find that it actually agrees with the numbers output by [your brute-force code snippet](http://pastebin.com/sxdAkgxn), which hover just below 2 -- are the graphs "right", or the code?)

Comment: Hmm... thanks for pointing out the graph inconsistencies, I'll check which is accurate. I notice now that in the question, I neglected to mention that I am not using the naive construction. The algorithm in question sums previously-calculated values, not raw values from the array. I didn't realize this wasn't the accepted method — I thought it seemed silly to do it the naive way. [The construction algorithm](http://pastebin.com/7aTP9t53)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer; your in-place algorithm is very interesting! I wonder if these two have the same efficiency?

Comment: OK, if you're *not* using the naive algorithm then a lot of what I've said is wrong...  I haven't seen the algorithm you linked to described anywhere else.  I believe it's essentially the same as mine (as David Eisenstat said in a comment on the SO page) -- but yours "pulls" values while mine "pushes" :)